# dragging and rotating a Rigidbody2D (with HingeJoint). Shadow Play / Puppetry Simulation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, draggable, mousewheel, unity3d-2dtools

I'm trying to make a program in Unity for playing around with shadow play puppets (mostly "Karagöz"). The characters i want to use made out of jointed limbs. There is a hole on their upperbody which allows to use sticks to move them behind curtain and rotate the bodies:
[Example1](http://www.buchmesse-ruhr.de/tl_files/buchmesse-ruhr/2014/Veranstalungen/karagoez/DSC_0159c.jpg)

I build the 2D characters with HingeJoints to simulate how they actually move. i think best way to move them is using mouse. You can drag them with mouse and use the scroll wheel to rotate the bodies.

I put a circle collider on the hole of the character and used a similar script like this [one](https://gist.github.com/nucleartide/7638121) to drag my character. My problem is the dragRigidbody2D solutions based on using a spring joint, and its just too springy for my usage and doesnt allow me to use rotating from the same point.

Has anyone an idea how to achive dragging and rotating 2D Rigidbodies with Hingejoints from this certain hole without making it springy / bouncey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is using Target Joint for dragging and `AddTorque` for rotating

Comment: Only works with google